# pimpl with inheritance using smart pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, pimpl-idiom

Please see my implementation of PIMPL with inheritance. In derived class, DerivedImpl inherits from BaseImpl.

Question:
Should the pointer to Impl only defined in base class like the following code? If so, every time I need to use the base pointer, I have to cast it to derived type. However, static cast a shared_ptr looks expensive according to profiling result because this cast is extensively used. And the cast function can't be inline in header because it is incomplete there.

Maybe I made some mistakes. Or is there better implementation for this using smart pointer?

```
// Base.h
class BaseImpl; // pre-declaration

class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    explicit Base(BaseImpl* ptr);
    ~Base();

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseImpl> d_Ptr;
};
```

---

```
// baseimpl.h
class BaseImpl
{
    double mDate;
};
```

---

```
// Derived.h
#include "Base.h"

class DerivedImpl;

class Derived :
    public Base
{
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();

    std::shared_ptr<DerivedImpl> d_func();
    const std::shared_ptr<DerivedImpl> d_func() const;
};
```

---

```
// Derived.cpp
#include "Derived.h"
#include "DerivedImpl.h"

Derived::Derived() : Base(new DerivedImpl())
{
}

Derived::~Derived()
{
}

std::shared_ptr<DerivedImpl> Derived::d_func()
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<DerivedImpl>(d_Ptr);
}

const std::shared_ptr<DerivedImpl> Derived::d_func() const
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<DerivedImpl>(d_Ptr);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to return a `shared_ptr` from `d_func`?

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where it makes sense to have a shared dynamically allocated implementation for a set of class instances. You should just use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @immibis I am not sure about this. If d_func returns a raw poitner, is there any risk of memory leak? (eg. d_func()->aMemberFunc() throws)

Comment: @YohWang If `d_func()->aMemberFunc()` throws, then that's got nothing to do with any memory leaks. A memory leak is when your program allocates something and forgets to deallocate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume that you want exactly what you describe, modulo implementation details:

- An inheritance hierarchy of public classes.
- Based on a corresponding inheritance hierarchy of implementation classes.
- The implementation's possible use of the global namespace and/or macros, should be confined to separately compiled units.

This is a problem, **derived class specific initialization**, that pops up e.g. when wrapping a set of low level GUI widgets in C++ classes. And also in many other situations. There is a wide range of possible solutions, but your so-far solution is to pass a pointer to implementation up through the base class constructors, to the top-most base, where it is provided to derived classes.

Still, you're not sure that that's a good idea:

> **”** Should the pointer to Impl only defined in base class like the following code?

Yes, ideally it should, because this approach ensures that an available base class instance is always fully constructed. And that's the basic idea of C++ constructors. That after initialization (e.g. of a base class sub-object), you either have a working object at hand, or nothing, i.e. exception or termination.

However, this approach serves you back two problems:

- How to efficiently provide derived class implementation pointer?
- How to at all derive an implementation from a base class implementation?

The latter problem is easily solved by having separate header files for the implementation. Keeping in mind that the point of information hiding is not to make these classes' source code physically inaccessible, although that's still possible. But to avoid pollution of the global namespace, and macro-land.

The first problem, which is what you actually ask about,

> **”** static cast a shared_ptr looks expensive according to profiling result because this cast is extensively used

is not really a problem.

The downcast functions need only be accessible in the implementation part of the code, and there their source code is available and the calls can be inlined.

Finally, just advice, you should use `unique_ptr`, or no smart pointer, or perhaps an automatically cloning smart pointer, rather than `shared_ptr`, for the implementation pointer. Because you generally don't want a copy of an instance of your public class, to share its implementation with the original instance. Other than for the case where the implementation has no state, in which case it's not very meaningful to allocate it dynamically.

---

Example:

*Base.hpp:*

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

namespace my {
    using std::unique_ptr;

    class Base
    {
    protected:
        class Impl;

    private:
        unique_ptr<Impl>    p_impl_;

    protected:
        auto p_impl() -> Impl* { return p_impl_.get(); }
        auto p_impl() const -> Impl const* { return p_impl_.get(); }

        Base( unique_ptr<Impl> p_derived_impl );

    public:
        auto foo() const -> char const*;

        ~Base();
        Base();
    };

}  // namespace my
```

*Base.Impl.hpp:*

```
#pragma once
#include "Base.hpp"

class my::Base::Impl
{
public:
    auto virtual foo() const -> char const* { return "Base"; }
    virtual ~Impl() {}
};
```

*Base.cpp:*

```
#include "Base.Impl.hpp"

#include <utility>      // std::move
using std::move;
using std::unique_ptr;

auto my::Base::foo() const
    -> char const*
{ return p_impl()->foo(); }

my::Base::~Base() {}

my::Base::Base()
    : p_impl_( new Impl() )
{}

my::Base::Base( unique_ptr<Impl> p_derived_impl )
    : p_impl_( move( p_derived_impl ) )
{}
```

*Derived.hpp:*

```
#pragma once
#include "Base.hpp"

namespace my {

    class Derived
        : public Base
    {
    protected:
        class Impl;

        Derived( unique_ptr<Impl> p_morederived_impl );

    private:
        auto p_impl() -> Impl*;
        auto p_impl() const -> Impl const*;


    public:
        ~Derived();
        Derived();
    };

}  // namespace my
```

*Derived.Impl.hpp:*

```
#pragma once
#include "Base.Impl.hpp"
#include "Derived.hpp"

class my::Derived::Impl
    : public my::Base::Impl
{
public:
    auto foo() const -> char const*  override { return "Derived"; }
};
```

*Derived.cpp:*

```
#include "Derived.Impl.hpp"

#include <utility>      // std::move
using std::move;
using std::unique_ptr;

inline auto my::Derived::p_impl() -> Impl*
{ return static_cast<Impl*>( Base::p_impl() ); }

inline auto my::Derived::p_impl() const -> Impl const*
{ return static_cast<Impl const*>( Base::p_impl() ); }

my::Derived::~Derived() {}

my::Derived::Derived()
    : Base( unique_ptr<Impl>( new Impl() ) )
{}

my::Derived::Derived( unique_ptr<Impl> p_morederived_impl )
    : Base( move( p_morederived_impl ) )
{}
```

*main.cpp:*

```
#include "Derived.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    wcout << my::Derived().foo() << endl;
}
```

---

Technicality: In class `Derived` the downcaster functions are `private`, to prevent them being used directly by a yet more derived class. That's because the implementations are `inline`, and should be defined identically in every translation unit where they're used. Rather than dividing this up into yet more headers, the more derived class should/can cast directly down from the `Base` implementation, just like `Derived` does.

Comment: This is what i need. I have two concerns. 1. Is it safe expose the raw pointer? Do I need to write more exception handling code? 2. I thought inline functions should be defined in header. But static_cast can't be done because Impl is only forward declared there. Thank you!

Comment: I think static_cast of raw pointer is cheap. The overhead of static_pointer_cast comes from the copy of shared_ptr. And here for my question 2, we can put the downcast in header as inline by using reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast.

Comment: Raw pointers are ungood for ownership, but they're all right for just referring to things. As long as one can prove that the referred to things have lifetimes exceeding the use of the raw pointers, which you get by default in this situation (but don't store the raw pointers anywhere). Re inline functions versus header files, the language specification is very file-agnostic, it doesn't deal in files at all. These particular two functions don't technically need to be member functions, however. I chose to let them be members for simpler notation, but they could just be inline free-standing funcs.

Comment: static_cast is cheap yes: it's most often a no-op, although in some cases it can adjust address. reinterpret_cast is seldom a solution, rather a problem. it is like a poisonous fish that sometimes is absolutely needed for dietary reasons, but one should better be careful, and generally avoid it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient answers. I learned a lot today.

Answer (score 1):

I think you defeat to purpose of the [Pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) by exposing the details of `BaseImpl` to the users of `Base`, not just to classes derived from `Base` but to all users of `Base` in general. For exactly the same reason, `DerivedImpl` also needs to be hidden.

I recommend the following:

```
// Base.h
class Base
{
   public:
      Base();
      virtual ~Base();

      // Add copy constructor and copy assignment operator too.
      // Follow the rule of Three/rule of Five.

      // Class that holds the implementation details of Base.
      class Impl;

   private:

      // Never expose the details of Impl
      // and never expose d_Ptr to clients.
      Impl* d_Ptr;
};
```

---

```
// Base.cpp

class Base::Impl
{
   // Add the necessary member variables and functions to facilitate
   // Base's implementation
};

Base() : d_Ptr(new Impl)
{
}

~Base()
{
   delete d_Ptr;
}
```

---

```
// Derived.h
#include "Base.h"

class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
      Derived();
      ~Derived();

      // Add copy constructor and copy assignment operator too.
      // Follow the rule of Three/rule of Five.

      // Class that holds the implementation details of Derived.
      // Has no relation to Base::Impl
      class Impl;

   private:

      // Never expose the details of Impl
      // and never expose d_Ptr to clients.
      Impl* d_Ptr;
};
```

---

```
// Derived.cpp

class Derived::Impl
{
   // Add the necessary member variables and functions to facilitate
   // Derived's implementation
};

Derived() : d_Ptr(new Impl)
{
}

~Derived()
{
   delete d_Ptr;
}
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, not recommended. I removed them.

Comment: @RSahu It looks not efficient to have a pointer to Impl in each derived class. The memory would be allocated repeatedly to construct a Derived class (two "new Impl" in your code.) And DerivedImpl may inherit some members from BaseImpl.

Comment: @YohWang, when you use the Pimpl idiom, you take on the extra allocation and deallocation overhead. You can do what you are trying but, IMO, it defeats the principle behind the Pimpl idiom.

Comment: @RSahu, Sometimes the impl holds a huge data member.(my case is a scientific lib). If I accept the overhead, how to achieve inheritance and polymophism through Impl. Or deriving Derived::Impl from Base::Impl also defeats Pimpl's principle.

Comment: @YohWang, if you feel that you need to inherit `Derived::Impl` from `Base::Impl`, I would say there is a flaw in your design. Whether `Impl` holds a huge data member that needs to be exposed, your classes are not amenable to the Pimpl idiom. If the data of `Base::Impl` needs to be exposed to `Derived::Impl`, you might be better of not using the Pimpl idiom at all. Put all the data in `Base` and make the data accessible through simple accessor and modifier functions.

Answer (score 0):

Old-ish discussion, but.. I've been pondering the idea of using the pimpl idiom in a hierarchy of classes and I don't see how it can be practical without adding polymorphic behavior to impls. Given one of the motivations of the pimpl idiom is vtable avoidance it would seem that once polymorphism is added to impls you are no longer using the pimpl idiom in its classic sense. Instead it is now more of a Bridge pattern. It can address similar concerns but its motivation is a bit different.